# Processing LiveData from Room database in ViewModel with Transformations.map

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have the following simple database:

`NameList.kt`

```
@Entity(tableName = "name_list")
data class NameList(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long = 0L,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        var name: String = "")
```

`NameListDao.kt`

```
@Dao
interface NameListDao{    
    @Insert
    fun insert(nameList: NameList)

    @Update
    fun update(nameList: NameList)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM name_list ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<NameList>>
}
```

`NameListRepository.kt`

```
class NameListRepository(private val nameListDao: NameListDao){
    val allNames: LiveData<List<NameList>> = nameListDao.getAll()
}
```

`MyViewModel.kt`

```
class MyViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app){
    private val nameListDao = NameListDatabase.getInstance(app).nameListDao
    private val repository: nameListRepository = nameListRepository(nameListDao)
    private val allNames: LiveData <List<NameList>> = repository.allNames
    ...
}
```

For the time being I want to get and process only the last entry of this non-empty database (without changing/adding methods in `NameListDao`).

Within a fragment, it is easy to get and e.g. display (in a `TextView` via data binding) the last database entry using the `observe` method:

```
viewModel.allNames.observe(this, Observer<List<NameList?>> { 
    nameList ->  binding.textView.text = nameList[nameList.lastIndex]!!.name 
})
```

As far as I found out, in `ViewModel` one needs to use `Transformations.map` or `Transformations.switchMap` to process `LiveData`.
I tried the following two (four) approaches with Transformations (none of which worked) in order to get the last entry of the database and pass it on to the method `doSomethingWithName()`. However, in all cases the passed parameter was apparently empty. (I also tried the first entry via `[0]`, but I got the same results though)

```
class MyViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app){
    private val nameListDao = NameListDatabase.getInstance(app).nameListDao
    private val repository: nameListRepository = nameListRepository(nameListDao)
    private val allNames: LiveData <List<NameList>> = repository.allNames

    private var _lastName = ""

    init{
        Transformations.map(allNames, ::getLastName1)          //first try
        //Transformations.switchMap(allNames, ::getLastName2)  //second try    

        doSomethingWithName(_lastName) //commented when executed in getLastName()
    }

    private fun doSomethingWithName(name: String){ ... }

    private fun getLastName1(nameList: List<NameList>){
        val names: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        nameList.forEach { names.add(it.name) } 
        val lastName = names[names.lastIndex]
        //doSomethingWithName(lastName) //third try
        _lastName = lastName
    }

    private fun getLastName2(nameList: List<NameList>): LiveData<NameList>{
        val liveData: MutableLiveData<NameList> = MutableLiveData(nameList[nameList.lastIndex])
        val lastName = liveData.value!!.name
        //doSomethingWithName(lastName) //fourth try
        _lastName = lastName
        return liveData
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't `NameListDatabase.getInstance(app).nameListDao` be done on a background thread? It initializes (and possible upgrades) the DB, no? Is it a singletone ? If it's safe on the UI thread, please show me the implementation of it. I ask because `Transformations.mapTransformations.map` is required to run on the UI thread, yet for DB, at least the initialization/upgrade should be done on a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last value in the list, considering the list might also be empty...

```
class MyViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app){
    private val nameListDao = NameListDatabase.getInstance(app).nameListDao
    private val repository: nameListRepository = nameListRepository(nameListDao)
    private val allNames: LiveData <List<NameList>> = repository.allNames
    private var _lastName = ""

    private val theLatestName =  MutableLiveData<NameList?>()
    init {
       allNames.observe(getAReferenceToaLifeCycleOwner, Observer{
         theLastestName.postValue(it.lastOrNull())
       })
       //make sure to get rid of the observer once this instance
       //of the viewmodel is destroyed
    }
```

}

Comment: So, basically, I need the Observer in any case. It confused me as I read multiple times that one shouldn't use it within the ViewModel and therefore tried without.

Comment: This is wrong. In [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) documentation
"However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects"